# Find empty cells in rows of a column | Dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My Dataframe has a column named "Teacher" and i want to know in that column the rows that are empty.
Example:

```
print(df["Teacher"])
0
1
2      Richard
3
4      Richard
Name: Teacher, Length: 5, dtype: object
```

I know that if i do something like this:

```
R = ['R']
cond = df['Teacher'].str.startswith(tuple(R))
print(cond)
```

It prints the rows of that column and tells me in boolean the teacher that starts with the R.

```
print(cond)
0      False
1      False
2      True
3      False
4      True
Name: Teacher, Length: 5, dtype: object
```

I want the same for the empty ones, to return True when its empty and false when its not but dont know how.

Comment: the problem here is that you actually don't have an empty row, you have rows with 0 length strings i.e `''` you need to replace them, then you can do a simple count. `df = df.replace('',np.nan,regex=True)` then `df[col].isna().value_counts()`

Comment: I dont want to replace the rows or count it , i want it to return booleans so i can then replace the Trues with strings or compare it with other booleans before changing it to strings, i found one line that gives me true in the ones that are with values and the other with false , dont know how to invert it and put true in empty and false in the ones that are with values ```cond =(df["Teacher"].notnull()) & (df["Teacher"]!=u'')```

Comment: Ok ```(df["Teacher"].notnull()) & (df["Teacher"]==u'')``` Does the trick ! Thanks anyways

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If empty is missing value or `None`s use [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html):

```
cond = df['Teacher'].isna()
```

If empty is zero or more spaces use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
cond = df['Teacher'].str.contains(r'^\s*$', na=False)
```

If empty is empty string compare by it:

```
cond = df['Teacher'] == ''
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Teacher':['',' ', None, np.nan, 'Richard']})

cond1 = df['Teacher'].isna()
cond2 = df['Teacher'].str.contains(r'^\s*$', na=False)
cond3 = df['Teacher'] == ''

df = df.assign(cond1= cond1, cond2= cond2, cond3= cond3)
print (df)

   Teacher  cond1  cond2  cond3
0           False   True   True
1           False   True  False
2     None   True  False  False
3      NaN   True  False  False
4  Richard  False  False  False
```

Comment: none of them worked .... i found one line that gives me true in the ones that are with values and the other with false , dont know how to invert it and put true in empty and false in the ones that are with values ```cond =(df["Teacher"].notnull()) & (df["Teacher"]!=u'')```

Comment: Ok ```(df["Teacher"].notnull()) & (df["Teacher"]==u'')``` Does the trick ! Thanks anyways